# Is there a way to put subcaption labels on the side?

Tags: captions, vertical-alignment, subcaption

I need to save space in a document, and I would like to reduce the space on the figures. I'm using the `subcaption` package for `subfigure`. Is it possible to do something like shown in the figure with this package?
[image]

I looked at the documentation and it seems I can place the (a) only above and below? I was using a different package before and I used to do it as follows:

```
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
```

Comment: And why do you want to not use the `floatrow` approach?

Comment: I understand that the sub caption package is supposed to supersede the other subfig and subfigure packages, right?

Comment: Yes, but not `floatrow`; `caption` focuses on the *formatting* of the captions and not specializes in positioning them; although it gives some possibilities, it's not as flexible as `floatrow `in this respect. From the documentation: "Please note that the `caption` package is only controlling the look & feel of the captions. It does
not control the placement of the captions. (But you could do so by using other packages like the
`floatrow` package[8].)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your question has the line

```
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
```

I assume here that you already know how to achieve what you want using the `floatrow` package plus `subfig` and that you are asking for an alternative approach with `subcaption`.

From the first page of the `caption` package documentation:

> Please note that the `caption` package is only controlling the look &
>   feel of the captions. It does not control the placement of the
>   captions. (But you could do so by using other packages like the
>   `floatrow` package[8].)

So, even though you can do this with `caption`/`subcaption` (see code below), there's not an out-of-the-box mechanism as the one provided by `floatrow`.

You can use `floatrow` as you were already doing. A possible alternative without `floatrow` can be achieved with the `subfigure` environment from the `subcaption` package and with the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package for easy vertical adjustment; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Cross-references to Figure~\ref{fig:test} and its subfigures~\ref{sfig:testa} and~\ref{sfig:testb}.
\begin{figure}
  \adjustbox{minipage=1.3em,valign=t}{\subcaption{}\label{sfig:testa}}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-1.3em\relax}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \adjustbox{minipage=1.3em,valign=t}{\subcaption{}\label{sfig:testb}}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-1.3em\relax}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{This is a figure}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, I noticed you have a great knowledge on LaTeX as you have almost replied to every question I had. How come you know so much about it? Do you develop packages for LaTeX

Comment: By the way, I can't get to put `\label` into those plots.

Comment: @aaragon Thanks for your kind words. Regarding your question: 1) Reading packages and classes code and studying answers from the great experts here is a great way to learn. 2) Yes, I've written two packages: `background` and `fancypar`  (some more are waiting for free time to see the light).

Comment: @aaragon Yes, you can use `\label` for the subfigures; please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you can change to `floatrow` and `subfig`, it's possible to do something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain, subcapbesideposition=top}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfloatrow}
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{subfloatrow}
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is already in the question. The OP is asking to do this with `subcaption` and not with `floatrow`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina OP says he is using `subcaption` but he doesn't say not to be open to other alternatives.

Comment: The question has the line `\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}` so obviously he knows how to do it with `floatrow`. I thinh he's asking for a way to do it without `floatrow` (why, it's a mistery since he didn't explain in the question).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Should I delete my answer?

Comment: I wrote a comment to the question asking for some clarification. Let's wait and see what the OP has to say.