# Warning errors for floats and subfloats in my main document

Tags: floats, subfloats

I found this piece of script to place three images all on top of each other

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{multicol, blindtext}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% \usepackage[english]{babel}     % Language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
\def\tablename{Table}%
}
% \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % Latin language
\usepackage{amsmath}            % For references to equations with \eqref
\usepackage{epstopdf}           % To be able to insert .eps figures when compiling with PDFLATEX
\usepackage{flushend}           % To match the columns of the last page
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\subfloat(a){%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}%
}

\subfloat(b){%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}%
}
\subfloat(c){%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}%
}

\label{fig:Nextel}

\caption[Grain size and strength development of  (a) Nextel 610, (b) Nextel 650, (c) Nextel 720 after heat-treatments between $1200^{o}$C and $1500^{o}$C (1 h)]{Grain size and strength development of  (a) Nextel 610, (b) Nextel 650, (c) Nextel 720 after heat-treatments between $1200^{o}$C and $1500^{o}$C (1 h) \citep{Schu:12}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, I get these warning messages for (a) and (c).

```
Undefined control sequence.

 
‪./reveiw.tex, 262‬
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}
```

I can't understand why there is no error message for (b), or how to remove the two error messages for this example.

Comment: Where does `\citep` come from? And which editor produces an error message like that? That is not from the LaTeX log

Comment: Off-topic: Do yourself a favor and (a) be sure to load the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package and (b) replace all instances of `$1200^{o}$C`, `$1500^{o}$C`, etc with `\qty{1200}{\celsius}`,  `\qty{1200}{\celsius}`, and so on.

Comment: @Alex it is frowned upon to edit your question in a way which invalidates existing answers. It is usually recommended to ask a new question instead. Also other than the missing images, your edited question compiles without error.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz edited back. Apologies.

Comment: @Mico that is a great tip, thanks

Comment: @AlexPoyser You did not exactly change it back - you are now loading the `natbib` package and compared to your original version, you are missing the `subfig` package. In summary: your now question invalidates all the answers you got!

Answer (score 3):

The complete error message reads like

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...^{o}$C and $1500^{o}$C (1 h) \citep 
                                                  {Schu:12}
l.22 ...}$C and $1500^{o}$C (1 h) \citep{Schu:12}}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Like the error message says, the control sequence at the end of the top line,  in your case `\citep`, is undefined.

`\citep` is not a default latex command. You either need to define it yourself or load a package which defines it, like `natbib`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{\citep{Schu:12}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do have natbib. Sorry, I should have added it to the preamble in the question or removed the` \citep ` to ask the question. Plus if I remove ` \citep ` I still get the two error messages

Comment: @AlexPoyser If your example does not reproduce the problem you have, it is difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your document example has many issues:

- Error is caused by missed package for formatting of cites (solved in @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz answer)
- It is not clear, does your sub images have subcaptions or not, and if have where should be paced. So I guess, that correct insertions of sub floats should be `\subfloat[ ]{\includegraphics{Images/deu.png}}`
- that all images will be above each other, you need to insert empty lines between them (now the first two are placed parallel)
- For quantities I would consider @Mico comment
- In caption you have both caption version (for FoC and for in document) equal. If this what you like to have, remove part in square brackets

MWE, which consider aforementioned, is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.5\columnwidth}
\sisetup{range-phrase = {\ \text{and}\ } }
    \centering
\subfloat[ ]{\includegraphics{Images/deu.png}}

\subfloat[ ]{\includegraphics{Images/ITA.png}}

\subfloat[ ]{\includegraphics{Images/USA.png}}

\caption{Grain size and strength development of  (a) Nextel 610, (b) Nextel 650, (c) Nextel 720 after heat-treatments between \qtyrange{1200}{1500}{\celsius} (\qty{1}{\hour}) \citep{Schu:12}.}
\label{fig:Nextel}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addition:**
In the case, that you like to have sub cations on the left side of images (this is not clear from your question, but document example may be understood on this way), than your code is a bit strange and would be more correct for example to consider @Ignasi answer on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273152/is-there-a-way-to-put-subcaption-labels-on-the-side). Its adoption to your case is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain, 
                    subcapbesideposition=top}% center or bottom
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.5\columnwidth}
    \sisetup{range-phrase = {\ \text{and}\ } }
    \captionsetup{labelfont={large, bf}}
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}} 

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}} 

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
\caption{Grain size and strength development of  (a) Nextel 610, (b) Nextel 650, (c) Nextel 720 after heat-treatments between \qtyrange{1200}{1500}{\celsius} (\qty{1}{\hour}) \citep{Schu:12}.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` and `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` I then get 13 errors.

Comment: @AlexPoyser, no. I tested my MWE: no errors, 3 warnings due to  undefined citations , no bad boxes. Cause of your errors is not in my MWE. BTW, you may have installed outdated packages. Try to refresh your LaTeX installation.

Comment: When using overleaf, I get the same undefined control sequence errors

Comment: @AlexPoyser, no, I tested my MWE again. No errors, two warnings  due to undefined citations . If you tested my MWE as it is, than you should got the same result as me, but if you change something in it or insert proposed solution in your document, than can happen that you in preamble some incompatible package, Without seeing errors, I cant say what is going wrong in your tests.